# RxJS Executing multiple asynchronous operation and wait for its completion the order in which executed

Tags: rxjs, mutex

```
/// ----------w1-----w2-----------------

/// -----------------------C1---------C2
```

There exist a write buffer, where command can be issued, once completed the callback fn associated with is called.

The requirement is write command should executed sequentially, for eg. if **w1** command is executed, and after that **w2**, **w2** should be executed once **w1** is completed. **w1** and **w2** should call their respective completion function **C1**, **C2** once they are completed.

Its implemented using RxJs, its working as per spec, but there are some pain points. Instead of using callback, I’m just using await to make the code flow linear.

```
function atomicWrite$(time, cmd) {
  return timer(time).pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(() => console.log('done cmd: ', cmd))
  );
}


const commandList = [];
let signalNextWrite$ = new ReplaySubject(1);

async function monsterProcess$(index, time) {

  console.log('entered loop', index);
  await signalNextWrite$.pipe(filter(idx => index === idx), take(1)).toPromise();

  console.log('processing start:', index, time);

  await of(commandList[index]).pipe(
    concatMap(cmd => atomicWrite$(time, cmd))
  ).toPromise();

  console.log('processing end:', index, time);

  signalNextWrite$.next(index + 1);

  return EMPTY.toPromise();
}

function writeIssue(command, time) {
  commandList.push(command);
  return monsterProcess$(commandList.length - 1, time);
}

signalNextWrite$.next(0);


setTimeout(async () => {
  const res = await writeIssue('windows xp2', 5000);
  console.log('completed windows');
});

setTimeout(async () => {
  const res = await writeIssue('mac siera', 1000);
  console.log('completed mac');
});
```

The question is instead of `signalNextWrite$`, can there be sometime like mutex which will wait till lock is unlocked and then continue.
Here index(idx) of command issued as filter which blocks the execution of other write command issued.

Wanted to move away from index of array as lock logic and instead use some other logic to wait, for current command to completed and signal the completion.

Also want to avoid this code also:

```
signalNextWrite$.next(0);
```

Stackblitz eg. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-r45p2d